# Is there a template for the comment links field?

Tags: entities, ajax, display-suite

I want to use [ajax-links-api](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) so that when someone replies to a comment,
the url comment/reply/60/51 is loaded with ajax on the current page.

I need to add rel="a class" on the reply link's anchor, to select witch div to load.

[image]

Display suite adds a manage display for comments

Is there a template file I can use to change the html for the comments field "links"?

> Update
>
> By Installing Devel and adding the block I see the comment wrapper [Devel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDITK.png)
>
> The template in modules/comment/comment.tpl does not look to have the html for links in it.[Comment Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBO2U.png)

Comment: install the `devel` module and assign the `Development` block in somewhere. then in theme regsitry look for comments. if it is not there you need register the comments in the theme registry then you will be able to add HTML to it.

Comment: Installing devel gets me further, but can you please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Do you know how to register a theme in theme registry?

Comment: No idea. Can you give me some basic detail of what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the default selectors to get the url? some thing like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("YOUR-COMMENTS-WRAPPER").find('a').click(function(){
             var url = $(this).attr('href');
        });
    )
    });
})(jQuery);
```

then use the `url` to load the `DIV`

Comment: using a script to add the necessary classes is the only solution I could find.